# What does this shell script code do?

Tags: shell

Help! I am trying to determine what the following shell script does:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter file name: \c"
read FILE

if [ $FILE = "example.txt" ]
then i=1

while [ $i -le 15 ]
do
    cp example.txt example$i.txt
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done

else 
   echo "ERROR"
fi
```

Can you help?

Comment: Please format the code sections of your question.

Comment: @hunteke already submitted an edit for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program apparently:

1. Prompts the user to input a filename
2. If the filename is equal to `example.txt`, makes 15 copies like `example1.txt`, `example2.txt`, etc.
3. Otherwise, it returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

User enters the file name
The program checks whether it is equal to example.txt
If Yes, then it creates 15 copies of it
If no then it displays ERROR